# Reading from SQL API after writing with MongoDB API using CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Let's say I'm adding the following document to CosmosDB collection called 'schoolInfo', using the MongoDB API.

```
var obj1 = {
    "type":"student"
    "studentId": "abc",
    "task_status": [
            {
                "status":"Current",
                "date":516760078
            },
            {
                "status":"Late",
                "date":1516414446
            }
        ],
    "student_plan": "n"
 }
```

(A) How do I create a SQL API Cosmos instance to read that same collection data?

I need the SQL API because I need to read that data in an Azure Function, and according to this, only SQL and Graph APIs are available for Azure Functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database#comments-container

(B) How would I query this from the SQL API? I'm assuming I can use `schoolInfo` as the Table Name, but how do I know/ensure Column Names are available - given that `task_status` is a nested/array object?

Any quick examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Cosmos DB APIs (other than SQL and Gremlin) are not inter-operable with each other yet. You can't use them interchangeably.

Comment: Is that a planned capability /do you happen to know of a timeline?

Comment: Particularly useful would be the ability to store as Mongodb, and query as SQL or Graph. (Might need some rule definitions of course)